# Get list of Paypal payout by date instead of ID

Tags: rest, paypal

I'm creating an application that lists your Paypal payouts. To do this the user grants access to me via the "Login with Paypal" functionality. I then take the access_token that I retrieve through the OAuth process and then I can fetch payouts with [this API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/).

The problem is that I don't have any payoutId (which is used to query this endpoint). Usually you can get all payouts with an endpoint that retrieves a list payouts by some criteria (like date range). How do I go about getting a list of payouts id I don't have the payout it? If that is not possible, where do I get a payout_id from?

Answer (score 0):

When sending payouts, a payout_batch_id is returned. Use that to query the batch's status.

Alternatively for notifications about payout items, [use Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#batch-payouts).

Comment: I'm not the one creating payouts so that is not possible. Regardingvwebhooks, how do I query older data?

Comment: Have the owner of the PayPal account download an activity log in CSV format from https://www.paypal.com/reports/dlog

Comment: This won't be a good user experience. Am I even looking at the correct end point to begin with? I want to connect the orders that has been placed on your shopify store with the transactions made into your paypal account

Comment: are there any solutions to this? is the API really built in such a way so that only the ones who have created a payout can retrieve that payout? @preston-phx